# Fancybox 2.1.5 not working correctly with jQuery 3.1.0

Tags: jquery, datatables, fancybox, fancybox-2

Not sure exactly what is causing this, but it seems the 'live' option isn't working. Same code and everything on my end except using jQuery 3.1.0 and the images open rather than fancybox opening. If I manually rerun my init command in the console all the links on the page work again :

```
$(".fancybox-screenshots").fancybox({
    prevEffect      : 'none',
    nextEffect      : 'none'
});
```

Is there a line in the fancybox js that needs modified for jquery 3? Seeing as how my code hasn't changed and it worked fine with jquery 2.x... just seems like the click handler no longer works and there is no binding to the class happening.

For what it is worth I am using DataTables as well so the actual loading of the content and links is as follows.  In my datatables init is where the fancybox images/links are output to the dom.  I init FancyBox after this happens.  Worked like a charm when using jQuery 2.x :

```
var ShowScreenshots = function () {

    var loadTable = function() {

        dt = $('#datatable').DataTable({
            //datatables.net stuff which includes loading the images/links for fancybox
        });


        // init the screenshots
        $(".fancybox-screenshots").fancybox({
            type : 'image',
            prevEffect      : 'none',
            nextEffect      : 'none',
            helpers     : {
                title   : { type : 'inside' },
                buttons : { tpl : '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul style="width: 203px;"><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnCustom" title="Save / Print" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li></ul></div>' }
            }
        });

    };


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            loadTable();
        }
    };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ShowScreenshots.init();
});
```

**EDIT :**

I'll add before someone brings it up... I have used the jquery migrate plugin for 3.x and it showed no serious errors or warnings.  I believe there was a deprecated warning, but that is just a warning for the future.

Comment: I don't see the word "live" in any of the code that you've posted, so I've got no context and I'm shooting blind here.  Googling "fancybox live option" doesn't give me the miracle of sight, either.  But wild guess here: there's a breaking change in jquery 3.0 involving the `live()` method, which has been obsolete since 1.9.  Googling "jquery 3.0 live" will show you the 3.0 upgrade guide which documents it.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs - 'live' is an option for FancyBox which is enabled by default and enables a click event handler.  Your guess isn't the issue here.

Comment: do you really need jquery 3.1?

Comment: I like to stay on top of the current versions.  Yes, I would like to use 3.1 lol.